# Ultimate member custom tab is not working after update

Tags: php, wordpress, ultimate-member

I'm using ultimate member for years, I created a custom tab in Edit Profile to update a value. In fact my users (students) can edit (add or remove) their pre-registered courses. The problem is that when they try to add or remove course, an error occurs, "An error has encountered". Surprisingly, they can remove the course even though it shows an error, but they can't add any course. It was working flawlessly till the latest update of Ultimate member. The code is as follows:

```
* */
/* create new tab */
  add_filter('um_account_page_default_tabs_hook', 'CoursesTab', 100 );
    function CoursesTab( $tabs ) {
    $tabs[800]['CoursesTab']['icon'] = 'um-faicon-pencil'; // tab icon
    $tabs[800]['CoursesTab']['title'] = 'Registered Courses'; // tab title
    $tabs[800]['CoursesTab']['submit_title'] = 'Update'; // button text
    $tabs[800]['CoursesTab']['custom'] = true;
    return $tabs;
  }

  /* make our new tab hookable */
  add_action('um_account_tab__CoursesTab', 'um_account_tab__CoursesTab');
    function um_account_tab__CoursesTab( $info ) {
    extract( $info );
    $output = UM()->account->get_tab_output('CoursesTab');
    if ( $output ) { echo $output; }
  }

  /* Finally we add some content in the tab */
  add_filter('um_account_content_hook_CoursesTab', 'um_account_content_hook_CoursesTab');
  function um_account_content_hook_CoursesTab( $output ){
    ob_start();
    $id = um_user('ID');
    $output = '<div class="um-field">';
    $names = array('course','course'); 

    $fields = array(); 
    foreach( $names as $name ){
      $fields[ $name ] = UM()->builtin()->get_specific_field( $name );
    }
    $fields = apply_filters('um_account_secure_fields', $fields, $id);
    foreach( $fields as $key => $data ){
      $output .= UM()->fields()->edit_field( $key, $data );
    }

    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
  }

  /* ensure that the custom fields are updated when the account is updated */
  add_action('um_account_pre_update_profile', 'getUMFormData', 100);

  function getUMFormData(){
    $id = um_user('ID');
    $names = array('course','course');  // ADD THE META-KEYS HERE
    foreach( $names as $name )
      update_user_meta( $id, $name, $_POST[$name] );
  }
```

I searched a lot, however, found no clue how to solve the issue.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I’ve added codes in this function:

```
add_filter('um_account_content_hook_CoursesTab', 'um_account_content_hook_CoursesTab');
function um_account_content_hook_CoursesTab( $output ){
    ob_start();
        $id = um_user('ID');
        $output = '<div class="um-field">';
        $names = array('course','course'); 

        $fields = array(); 
        foreach( $names as $name ){
        $fields[ $name ] = UM()->builtin()->get_specific_field( $name );
        }
        $fields = apply_filters('um_account_secure_fields', $fields, $id);
        foreach( $fields as $key => $data ){
        $output .= UM()->fields()->edit_field( $key, $data );
        }

        $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="um_account_nonce_'. esc_attr( 'coursestab' ).'" value="'.esc_attr( wp_create_nonce( 'um_update_account_coursestab' ) ).'" />';
                                    
        $output .= '</div>';

        $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $output;
}
```

I’ve added a hidden nonce field:

```
$output .= '<input type="hidden" name="um_account_nonce_'. esc_attr( 'coursestab' ).'" value="'.esc_attr( wp_create_nonce( 'um_update_account_coursestab' ) ).'" />';
```

Please try it and let me know if you’re still encountering issue.

Regards,